# Solving Josephus with linked lists

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, josephus

I've been tryin for a while but i cant figure out how to make the program below take N as input and generate an M in order that the last soldier that dies is the 13th(N>13);

```
 int main()
 {
 int N, M;
 struct node { int player_id; struct node *next; };
 struct node *p, *q;
 int i, count;

 printf("Enter N (number of players): "); scanf("%d", &N);
 printf("Enter M (every M-th payer gets eliminated): "); scanf("%d", &M);

// Create circular linked list containing all the players:

p = q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

p->player_id = 1;

for (i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {
    p->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p = p->next;
    p->player_id = i;
}

p->next = q;//Close the circular linkedlist by having the last node point to the 1st   

// Eliminate every M-th player as long as more than one player remains:

for (count = N; count > 1; --count) {
   for (i = 0; i < M - 1; ++i)

 p = p->next;       p->next = p->next->next;

  // Remove the eiminated player from the circular linked list.
     }    printf("Last player left standing is %d\n.", p->player_id);

   return 0;
  }
```

the result should be the same as [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=ApstxUmbjpOFetygfN5z2oMazKIX;_ylv=3?qid=20130521084057AATv8xT) one(but I need it in linked lists cos i dont understand that one):>.

Comment: If somebody wants to see the problem, it is here: http://bit.ly/JTeFaW

Comment: yes mate thats the problem i translated mine from a book in my language who looks like copied that one

Comment: There is a closed form solution to the Josephus problem. No need to write all this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read all the code above, I think it can find the last item for given `N` and `M`

According to the original problem, `12<N<100`. So, probably it can be solved in the given time limit simply with brute force.

- You read in `N`
- start a loop for finding `m` from 1
- in the loop:

  - run the algorithm, using the loop variable as `m`. If the last item is 13, return the loop variable.

EDIT:
You don't have to work a lot. You just simply start a loop instead of reading `M`.

```
M=1;
while(1)
{
//your code goes here: 
//build up the linked list with N element
//eliminate the nodes, until only one remains
//instead of writing out the last number, you check it: if it equals 13 print M, if doesn't, increment `M` and continue the loop.
 if(p->player_id==13)
 {
   printf("The minimal M is: %d\n", M);
   break;
 }
 else
   M++;
}
```

If You want to do this for multiple `N`-s, You can put this loop into a function. In this case insted of printing `M`, the function should return it.
The funny thing is: The linked list part is done by You. Maybe You should try simpler exercises first.

EDIT 2:
[HERE](http://ideone.com/4GWhu1) is my final answer, check the structure and the output, I hope it is understandable.

NOTE:
I think if You really want to learn, You should do something like this instead of jumping in a not trivial problem:

- understand pointers
- understand structs
- understand linked lists
- implement insert/update/delete to the head/tail/certain position of a  linked list
- solve Josephus problem by Yourself in 10 minutes

Comment: yeah that was my guess but i actually can't figure it out how to start that loop since i'm a newb and linked list are a pain for me.

Comment: @RediRedi I tried to explain it, You should just keep trying now.

Comment: @RediRedi that's a good solution - go for it. Just do the loop that check all possible M values and when it gives You 13 get the value that loop was currently on

Comment: @pivovarit yeah i fixed that one i just applied your changes to my previous code thanks again... something else though see i need to print all the eliminations like 1,8,14........13 how to do that one

Comment: @RediRedi damn, I already got You an answer ;) if You want to print eliminations just insert a print statement into the loop just before the removal of the element

Comment: @RediRedi The code in Your question contains the solution. There is access to the value of a node. There is printf function too. Please try to use them.

Comment: @pivovarit  p->next = p->next->next; printf("%d\n",*p->next->next); Thhis didn't give me the result i was expecting ;p (i feel dumb)

Comment: @RediRedi check my answer to this question below

Comment: @pivovarit  printf("M = %d eliminating: %d \n",i,p->player_id);
   p->next = p->next->next; that didnt work either

Comment: @pivovarit I don't think so. This is Your code: http://ideone.com/AfpWwf (I replaced some `node` with `struct node` and included the two needed headers). The final result is correct, but the output is very strange.

Comment: @RediRedi the code finds the right solution - just refine the printf line so that it matches in 100% what You want. If You wrote most if this code it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @pivovarit as gkovacs90 said the output is strange and i'm getting the same output no matter what i've tried.The output im looking for is this http://ideone.com/0cVTRT.

Comment: @RediRedi I provided a link with the correct output too. The only difference is: I don't scan `N`, just run the minimal`M`-finding method for `N=17`

Comment: @gkovacs90 oops i didn't see that hang on imma try if i can get the smae output while scanning N.

Comment: You definitely should get the same output(Note: if You try with `N<13` , the loop will be infinite.) Btw, the problem is solved, These are just extras.

Comment: @gkovacs90 and pivovarit i think i solved it thanks a lot to both of you.P.S:A friend of mine owns you a beer.

Comment: @gkovacs90 i've dont the last modifications but i think i'm asked to just post only the last part i.e: input :N=17  Output:M=7 Exectutions:1,8,15,.......13.I've been thing for the last hour and the only solution that comes in my mind is by using Stacks(but i haven't learnt those yet...) and my deadline is tomorrow so here i am asking for help again.

Comment: @pivovarit that works for you too :P   P.S my almost final code:http://ideone.com/8WF4OD

Comment: Just give some stop-condition( in this case, if N=0, it will stop). It works. Check: http://ideone.com/ZtcKnU

Comment: @gkovacs90 i doubt i made myself clear :) i meant to only printf the last line of executions,the one where 13 is the last one standing

Comment: I won't write this one. The simplest solution for You is the following:  
Don't print anything until You find the minimal M. This is easy, just comment out the printf functions. When You've found it, run the algorithm once again without the loop, only for the M you've found. This will be only a little copy-paste work. The code will be redundant, but it will work.

Comment: got it working on it tomorrow morning will post update if i fix it;cant believe it was this easy