# Linked list issue - loop iterates over wrong nodes

Tags: c, loops, data-structures, linked-list, josephus

If you are not familiar with Josephus problem:

There are N soldiers standing in a circle.They all get executed starting by 1 and moving by M.In the end only one of them stands alive.
the code below ask for N and M and generated the last player standing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int N, M;
struct node { int player_id; struct node *next; }
struct node *p, *q;
int i, count;

printf("Enter N (number of players): "); scanf("%d", &N);
printf("Enter M (every M-th payer gets eliminated): "); scanf("%d", &M);

// Create circular linked list containing all the players:

p = q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

p->player_id = 1;

for (i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {
    p->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p = p->next;
    p->player_id = i;
}  

p->next = q;// Close the circular linkedlist by having the last node point to the 1st  

// Eliminate every M-th player as long as more than one player remains:

for (count = N; count > 1; --count) {
   for (i = 0; i < M - 1; ++i)
      p = p->next;

   p->next = p->next->next;  // Remove the eiminated player from the circular linkedl
}

printf("Last player left standing is %d\n.", p->player_id);

return 0;
}
```

Lets say N=17;M=7 the output should be 13
the program above generates 2 (what happens? well it starts the counting from M not from 1 so instead of 1,8,15...... it elimintates 7,14......)
This is where i need your help (as linked lists are still a difficult concept for me).
How to modify this one?

Comment: Haven't I seen the Josephus lately in another question? And where are your `#include` directives? This is a gerbil of code that you should turn into something sane before asking.

Comment: @Jens it should always start with 1?

Comment: yes @pivovarit always starts from 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed the node removal line in the wrong place.

```
for (count = N; count > 1; --count) {
   for (i = 0; i < M - 1; ++i)
      p = p->next;

   p->next = p->next->next;
}
```

You placed this line **after** the loop that count M nodes from the beginning so it always start with removal of (M+1)th node. You should move it **before** it so that it starts from the first node.

```
for (count = N; count > 1; --count) {
   p->next = p->next->next;
            for (i = 0; i < M - 1; ++i) p = p->next;

}
```

Is this what You're looking for?

Comment: @RediRedi You were already very close ;) You can thank me by accepting the answer. Cheers!

Comment: if you have time take a look at [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875295/anyone-familiar-with-josephus-prablemlinked-lists-in-c?noredirect=1#comment24364503_16875295)

Comment: @RediRedi You can 'tick' the answer if it solves your problems and upvote (up arrow) if You think that solution is ok. It gives me and you reputation points and also show another people what answer is the most important for the particular problem. Those buttons are next to the answer. I will have a look at your another question

Comment: @pivovarit FYI - [You need 15 reputation to upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). And you should upvote if "you feel [it] is **especially** useful".

Comment: @Dukeling that for the explenation :p i would upvote it but i cant

Comment: @RediRedi isn't the problem from another question already solved here?

Comment: @pivovarit at the other question:Input N Output:M  (last player standing is always 13)

Comment: @pivovarit being more precise i need to solve [this](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=87) using linked list